# ScalaTest for Scala 2.11.4?

Tags: maven, scalatest

Is there a [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/) available for Scala `2.11.4` in Maven?

I tried what appeared to be the latest [version](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.11/3.0.0-SNAP2).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAP2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

However, when building via `mvn clean install`, I see:

`[WARNING]  org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:3.0.0-SNAP2 requires scala version: 2.11.2`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.scalatest.org/download

there's all the configuration examples,for you I think this is suitable

Here's the code for your Maven POM (for Scala 2.11.0+):

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>`

and why don't you use sbt, it's a  better build tools for pure scala coder.